# Loading a delimited file with variable number of columns into a database using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I may get text files with variable number of columns. The data can be like below.

```
1,a,x
2,b
3,c,y,z
```

Now i have to load all the rows into the database say postgres\ sql server. The table schema is as below

```
Table : test
columns : col1 (nvarchar(max)),col2 (nvarchar(max)),col3 (nvarchar(max))
```

The data should be loaded as below

```
col1   col2   col3
1       a       x
2       b       Null
3       c       y,z
```

So these are the rules for loading
1) If number of columns in file are less than the columns in table, missing columns should be replaced by nulls
2) If the number of columns in file are greater than the columns in table, all extra data should be saved in last column.

Could someone suggest me the best way to accomplish this

Comment: The maximum number of columns are not fixed and unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, reading the file using `pd.read_fwf`.

```
df = pd.read_fwf(filename, delimiter=',', header=None)
```

Now we have to concatenate all columns after 'col3' into col3:

```
df.iloc[:,2] = df.iloc[:,2:].astype(str).apply(tuple, axis=1).str.join(',').str.replace(',nan', '')

df = df.iloc[:,:3]
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

> **Example**

data in `filename:`

```
1,a,x
2,b
3,c,y,z
4,d,s,f,d,s
```

Df when reading the file using `pd.read_fwf`:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   a   x   NaN NaN NaN
1   2   b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   3   c   y   z   NaN NaN
3   4   d   s   f   d   s
```

Output after the above operation:

```
   col1  col2   col3
0   1      a    x
1   2      b    nan
2   3      c    y,z
3   4      d    s,f,d,s
```